# Performance load testing using Jmeter and how assets files may affect the results

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Good Day Folks,

I have been playing around with `Jmeter` for a load testing project. I was looking for a way that simulates **Full / Real user behavior** starting by loading the *Home page* for the app, Doing the login, Then Send a predefined message to a certain user, And load all assets files and Images, not just the direct `API` CALLS.

> Doing the previous steps using a straightforward way will be a bit complicated and It will take a longer time.

I have found this chrome extension **([BlazeMeter | The Continuous Testing Platform](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi))** That help with Recording set of actions and export it in Jmeter format.

[image]

## But,

It does only records the direct API calls and does not load any asset or socket/WebSocket sessions.

[image: The Continuous Testing Platform].

Figuring that we may use [Selenium driver](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integrating-jmeter-selenium/) with Jmeter may solve this state. But it won't be a good approach to follow if you're going to test with 10k users or even more (*Resources limitation*).

Any recommendation or workaround?

Comment: [JMeter WebSocket Sampler
]https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter/

Comment: I'm curious, how do you plan on using selenium with jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:-

1. Distributed mode with selenium using Grid.
2. Go to cloud base execution that can provide parallel execution with so many number of Vusers.

First one is hectic and you need to have very good/powerful system and resources to make it work along with sync problems and consolidation. I think easier would be to go with selenium and use a cloud base system to run the script in parallel with 10K Vusers.